# Optimising Team Ratings in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, optimization

Generally speaking, the aim is to maximise the negative log-likelihood (or minimise the positive log likelihood) by optimising parameters resulting in convergence. These parameters, in context, are Attack Ratings, Defence Ratings, Standard Deviation, and a generic Home Advantage. The first 3 parameters will be vectors (with length the number of teams in the competition) and they are team specific, and Home Advantage will just be a scalar.`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.optimize


# Reads the game data
game = pd.read_csv('Games.csv') 
numGames = len(game) # Number of Games
homeadv = 1.1 # Home Advantage
```

The first two rows of the raw pandas DataFrame read in above looks like this:

```
   Game Home ID Away ID Home Points Away Points
    1     1        2        62         59
    2     3        4        81         82
```

Collating the ID's of the teams and Initial Parameter Guesses

```
id_list = sorted(pd.unique(pd.concat([game['HomeID'], game['AwayID']], axis=0)))

# Attack Parameters, Defence Parameters, Standard Deviation Parameters, and Home Advantage set to an arbitrary value
attackratings = [5 for id in id_list]
defenceratings = [5 for id in id_list]
stdevratings = [2 for id in id_list]
homeadv = 1.1 # Home Advantage for the Team playing at home

# Put into a tuple for the scipy.optimize.minimize
init_params = tuple(attackratings + defenceratings + stdevratings + [homeadv])
```

Lists for each parameter - _h signifys Home and _a signifys Away

```
attack_h = []
defence_a = []
st_dev_h = []
st_dev_a = []
attack_a = []
defence_h = []

for i in range(0,len(game)):
    x = attackratings[id_list.index(game.HomeID[i])]
    attack_h.append(x)
    x = defenceratings[id_list.index(game.AwayID[i])]
    defence_a.append(x)
    x = stdevratings[id_list.index(game.HomeID[i])]
    st_dev_h.append(x)
    x = stdevratings[id_list.index(game.AwayID[i])]
    st_dev_a.append(x)
    # Home Def and Away Att
    x = attackratings[id_list.index(game.AwayID[i])]
    attack_a.append(x)
    x = defenceratings[id_list.index(game.HomeID[i])]
    defence_h.append(x)

game['attack_h'] = attack_h
game['defence_a'] = defence_a
game['attack_a'] = attack_a
game['defence_h'] = defence_h
game['st_dev_h'] = st_dev_h
game['st_dev_a'] = st_dev_a
```

Calculating each team's probability of getting those points given the parameters:

```
game['exp_home'] = scipy.stats.norm.pdf(game.HomePts,game.attack_h*game.defence_a*homeadv,game.st_dev_h*game.st_dev_a)
game['exp_away'] = scipy.stats.norm.pdf(game.AwayPts,game.attack_a*game.defence_h,game.st_dev_h*game.st_dev_a)
```

The next step is to find the log likelihood for each match, which is simply the product of `exp_home` and `exp_away`

```
game['loglik'] = np.log(game['exp_home']*game['exp_away'])
```

So the sum of `game['loglik']` is the thing that needs to minimised, but I am not sure how to go about doing so.

My efforts so far have failed miserably, but the code below is essentially what I'm after for the loss function:

```
def logsum(params,game,id_list):
    lt = -np.sum(game.xy)
    return lt

W = scipy.optimize.minimize(logsum, x0=init_params, args=(game, id_list))
```

I am fairly new to Python, but any help would be really appreciated! And please, if the explanation above is unclear, fire away any questions.